# How to continuously spawn a certain block underneath myself?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is the command:

```
execute at <player> run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:oak_planks
```

I've also tried spawning it underneath the command block, but that does not work either.
I did try using `/setblock` normally, and it does work, so I'm not really sure where I've gone wrong.

Version is 1.17.

Comment: What are you using in place of `<player>`? Are you using your username, or a target selector?

Comment: Strangely enough, your command also works. Maybe you typed in your username wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your command is correct. You may have typed your username incorrectly.
An alternative to `execute at` is using `execute positioned as <player> run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:oak_planks`, but this will not work if you are in a different dimension.

Also, make sure you are running the command on a repeat command block.

Comment: I apologize for that. I edited the command syntax and tested the command. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Comment: Very good, thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `as <player>`

For example:

```
execute as <player> run setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:oak_planks
```

You also should not need the `at <player>` when it is being ran by `as <player>` the cords at set block (`~ ~ ~`) should do that